# Determine DPI of Image in Java

Tags: java, jai

I have a TIFF image that has been read in to my application and is stored in a `BufferedImage` object. How can I determine the horizontal and vertical DPI of the image using the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) APIs? I have been looking around and not been able to find a straight forward way to accomplish this.

Comment: If all you have is a `BufferedImage`, you are out of luck.. If you have a reference to a file, stream or similar, I suggest looking into the ImageIO API, especially `ImageReader.getImageMetadata()`, getting the DPI from there should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: The data comes to me as a byte array from a web service call. I think I can go back to the point I initially read it from the byte array to try out an `ImageReader`. Then pass the DPI info along to the point at which I need it. My next stumbling block seems to be that when I try to do `ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff")` to load the reader it says that it cannot find a reader of that type. Still trying to figure out how to resolve that.

Comment: I keep finding out how complex the Java imaging APIs are and how little I know about them...

Comment: Hard to disagree about the complexity.. :-/ To the TIFF issue: There's a couple of TIFF plugins for ImageIO around. You can use jai-imageio, it supports metadata in both standard and native format. I'd like to recommend my own plugin as well, but it doesn't yet support metadata. :-)

Comment: What is your plugin? Not sure if I will be using it for this project, but it might be useful to know about in the future.

Comment: You can find [my ImageIO plugins](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) on GitHub. TIFF read/write is work in progress at the moment, but getting there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a full example extracting DPI (well, pixels per mm, really) using the standard ImageIO API and the standard metadata format. Complexity, here we come... :-P

```
public class DPITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File(args[0]);

        ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

        if (readers.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            reader.setInput(stream);

            IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
            IIOMetadataNode standardTree = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(IIOMetadataFormatImpl.standardMetadataFormatName);
            IIOMetadataNode dimension = (IIOMetadataNode) standardTree.getElementsByTagName("Dimension").item(0);
            float horizontalPixelSizeMM = getPixelSizeMM(dimension, "HorizontalPixelSize");
            float verticalPixelSizeMM = getPixelSizeMM(dimension, "VerticalPixelSize");

            // TODO: Convert pixelsPerMM to DPI left as an exercise to the reader.. ;-)  

            System.err.println("horizontalPixelSizeMM: " + horizontalPixelSizeMM);
            System.err.println("verticalPixelSizeMM: " + verticalPixelSizeMM);
        }
        else {
            System.err.printf("Could not read %s\n", input);
        }
    }

    private static float getPixelSizeMM(final IIOMetadataNode dimension, final String elementName) {
        // NOTE: The standard metadata format has defined dimension to pixels per millimeters, not DPI...
        NodeList pixelSizes = dimension.getElementsByTagName(elementName);
        IIOMetadataNode pixelSize = pixelSizes.getLength() > 0 ? (IIOMetadataNode) pixelSizes.item(0) : null;
        return pixelSize != null ? Float.parseFloat(pixelSize.getAttribute("value")) : -1;
    }
}
```

Some sources to read:

- [The ImageIO API guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/imageio_guideTOC.fm.html)
- [ImageIO standard metadata format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html)
- [The JAI ImageIO TIFF plugin (esp. metadata format)](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/package-summary.html#ImageMetadata)

Comment: Wow, they definitely don't make JAI easy to figure out... I really feel like I'm in over my head with it sometimes (and I'm not exactly new to Java). So, it looks like I can pass in an `InputStream` to `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` rather than a `File` which should work for what I'm doing. Will try this when I return to the office Monday. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I'm curious is there some resource I'm overlooking for figuring out how to accomplishing things or is it really just 'trial and error' digging through the API docs to figure things out?

Comment: @Michael This is just the ImageIO API, not JAI specific (but jai-imageio does provide the TIFF ImageReader plugin which implements this API), so try googling for that. But not sure if there's a "definitive guide" out there... `InputStream` should do fine. I'll update the answer with some pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This code seems to work for what I wanted. I was able to convert the pixel size to DPI and it gave me the numbers I was expecting. I ended up downloading the TIFFReader from https://java.net/projects/imageio-ext to make this work.

Comment: That wouldn't be an integer, fe: 0.0846 for 300DPI, use Double.valueOf instead of

Comment: @DanielHári Good catch! In the format, the values are defined as "Float", so I updated the code to use that (`float`). `double` would work just as well.

Comment: createImageInputStream is returning null for me.  Documentation says this is caused by "no suitable ImageInputStreamSpi exists".  How do I deal with that?

Comment: @MichaelPotter What are you passing to `createImageInputStream(..)`? There are built-in Spis (Service Provider Interfaces) for `File`, `InputStream` and `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: I am passing File.  I basically converted your main() to a function. I am running on a Mac so maybe that is what is different.  I ended up using constantlearners solution, but I voted you up because your example is so good.

Comment: @MichaelPotter Thanks! :-) I'm using a Mac too (most of the time), so I doubt that to be the case... Most likely your file name is wrong, or the file isn't readable (by the Java process). In this case `FileImageInputStreamSpi` may return `null` (incorrectly), due to a very strange `catch (Exception) {return null;}`, shadowing the real cause. I think you should have got an `IOException` in this case, but the API doc is somewhat vague...

Answer (score 4):

Apache Commons Sanselan library to get image info:       http://commons.apache.org/imaging/index.html.

```
final ImageInfo imageInfo = Sanselan.getImageInfo(file);

final int physicalWidthDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalWidthDpi();
final int physicalHeightDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalHeightDpi();
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without using Commons Imaging? I'd prefer not to have to include an extra library for this one task. Also, to use this method I have to encode it back into a byte array. If I do so without specifying the DPI settings in the `TIFFEncodeParam` the code above returns -1 for both values. If I specify DPI settings to the encoder I do get a value, but obviously it will be the DPI that I specify, not the original value for the image.